# CSS variable to SASS variable = problem with opacity function

Tags: html, css, variables, sass, opacity

consider this problem... two .scss sheets

```
*styles.scss*
@import _variables.scss

--app-color: rgb(0,0,0); //css variable
```

---

```
*_variables.scss*

$color: var(--app-color); //CSS to SASS variable
```

---

now we can everywhere use $color variable filled with CSS variable color and it works.

My problem is using this SASS/CSS variable to set opacity. Look at this =>

```
background: rgba($color, .1);
```

it will NOT work... because $color in this case will not be passed like common color value like I defined (

> rgb(0,0,0)

) but like (

> var(--app-color)

and function rgba() probably don't know
how to handle this parameter.

rgba() can handle two parameters ($color, $alpha) which works perfectly, but not if $color/$alpha are filled with CSS variables values )

... any idea how to solve this? Am I wrong with how I understand it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaking the css [functional notation for color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgba) and the [sass rgba() function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgba-instance_method) they may have a similar syntax but they are totally different functions. The first one requires three parameters and the second one will work only when its two parameters are passed before compilation and therefore cannot work with css variables which can change at any time.